# Hide application from menu and show when we want to

Tags: android

I want to hide my app from main menu, when user want to, s/he can see their app.

To hide the app I've removed the launcher category, and for now the app get hidden but now I don't understand how can the user launch the app. I've read somewhere that using a key combination (on the DialerPad) one can show the main screen of activity. How is this done?
Any other ideas of launcher an app when a launcher is not present?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Why should you app not be displayed in the launcher?

Comment: @reno thanks a lots...expecting an answer also from your side

Comment: @Flo. actually client want to change app's label and icon anytime , so that no one can recgnize this in user phone,...which is not possible so we found a way if we can hide it and show it when user wants

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can hide your application icon but only on rooted devices or system signed apps.....the solution will be to first disable your application using shell command **`pm disable com.yourapppackagename`** and then enable it back using `**pm enable com.yourapppackagename**` this will first disable your app removing app icon from device and then enabling back your app will bring back the app icon only in device menu and not on homescreen. if you want to **disable** and then **enable** on user choice then you may create a toggle button such as when **off** then **disable** your app and when **on** then **enable** your app.It will definatly work i have already worked on something similar